# Value of a variable not changing in javaFX

Tags: variables, javafx

I'm trying to make a program using Javafx, and I essentially want to have to press a certain button twice. The context of my objective is less important as I just want to know why my code isn't working as expected.

```
  if(event.getSource() == next)
  {
     boolean state = true;
     if (state = false){
         System.out.print("testing " + state);
         normalGUI();
         state = true;
     }
     else{
        state = false;
        System.out.print("test2");
     }
     state = false;
  }
```

My output:

----jGRASP exec: java PokemonGUI
test2test2

Why isn't it changing the state to false, it should definitely be happening in my eyes. Thanks for any help you provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Each time you put the same action (this action create a new boolean initialized as True) :

```
boolean state = true;
```

And So, changing the value won't affect anything here :

```
state = false;
```

To solve the problem try to change your variable to global, like this :

```
 boolean state = true;
 if(event.getSource() == next)
 {

 if (state == false){
     System.out.print("testing " + state);
     normalGUI();
     state = true;
 }
 else{
    state = false;
    System.out.print("test2");
 }

 }
```

Comment: Wow, major brainfart there. Thanks a ton it was sitting right infront of me